# Installing cutadapat package in windows

Tags: windows, python-3.5

I'm trying to install a package name cutdapt in a windows server. I'm trying to do it this way: 
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org cutadapt

But every time I try to install it I get this error: Building wheel for cutadapt (PEP 517): finished with status 'error'

Any ideas on how to pass this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, that I had some problems with python 3.5, so I switched to python 3.8 and managed to install the package.